# Identical results with different model parameters

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, nlp, word-embedding

I'm making a neural network model to assign sentiments to phrases. My problem is no matter what I change in my model, the accuracy score is always identical.

I have tried adding or removing layers, changing batch size, changing number of epochs, changing activators etc.

```
tokenizer = Tokenizer()
total_phrases = phrases_train.append([phrases_valid,  phrases_test], 
                                     ignore_index = True) 

tokenizer.fit_on_texts(total_phrases)

maxlen = max([len(s.split()) for s in total_phrases])

vocab_size = len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1

phrases_train_tokens = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(phrases_train)
phrases_valid_tokens = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(phrases_valid)
phrases_test_tokens = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(phrases_test)

pad_phrases_train = pad_sequences(phrases_train_tokens, maxlen=maxlen, 
                                  padding='post') 
pad_phrases_valid = pad_sequences(phrases_valid_tokens, maxlen=maxlen, 
                                  padding='post') 
pad_phrases_test = pad_sequences(phrases_valid_tokens, maxlen=maxlen, 
                                 padding='post')

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, 100, input_length=maxlen))
model.add(Dense(50, kernel_initializer='truncated_normal', 
                activation='relu'))
model.add(GRU(units=32, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics= 
              ['accuracy'])

model.fit(pad_phrases_train, sents_train, batch_size=250, epochs=50, 
          validation_data=(pad_phrases_valid, sents_valid), verbose=2)

model.evaluate(pad_phrases_test, sents_test)
```

Evaluate always shows exactly 0.2057 score. I want to achieve around 50% accuracy

Comment: You could try instantiating [`Adam`](https://keras.io/optimizers/#adam) and adjust learning-rate. What are you predicting? Is 20% of your test-data e.g. class 0 and your model simply predicts 0 on all? What is your training accuracy?

Comment: I'm predicting sentiments of phrases. Sentiments are numbers from 0 to 4. Train data is around 80k phrases and validation and test sets are both 8k phrases. My traning accuracy is always 0.1673 and val_acc is always 0.1948

Comment: Adjusting learning rate doesn't help either.

Comment: Can you test a couple of inputs and see if it always predicts the same? Or check your distribution of classes? You could also change your output layer to have 5 neurons, and encode your labels as one-hot vectors. Softmax activation will make the output a probability between 0 and 1, so maybe that's problematic for an output layer with 1 neuron.

Comment: Probably it is predicting everything as a certain class.

Comment: Yeah, this was the issue. Encoding output variable and 5 neurons in output layer helped to resolve it.